# JavaScript Determine Cause for Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Suppose a DOM element has focus.  Is there a way to take action **X** if the user presses *enter* and the `click` event will be fired, but to take action **Y** if the element is `click`ed by any means other than by pressing *enter*?

**-- More Details --**

I am using a jQuery plugin ([bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)) over which I have no control.  This plugin registers for `click` events on elements within the DOM.  Now, I want to modify the behavior so additional actions occur prior to firing the registered `click` event handler, depending on how the event was initiated.

I have come up with two approaches, both of which require registering for the `mouseup` and `keydown` events.

1. Set global variable from within the `mouseup` and `keydown` event handlers to cache the event properties, then access this global variable in the `click` handler.  Since there is no guarantee about what fires the `click` handler, I have to set a timeout to clear this global variable.  This introduces threading issues.
2. Hard code the events that I think will cause a `click` event to be fired.  Based on experience, this happens when either `e.type == 'mouseup' && e.button == 0` or `e.type == 'keydown' && (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32)`.  The problem with this logic is that it assumes that these are the only ways that the `click` event handler is fired.  I could envision some user agents enable changing the keys that ultimately send a `click` event to the underlying object.  Perhaps touch-screens have some other event that is fired when clicking on the DOM element.

The refined version of my question is whether there is any way to either...

1. Ensure that these `mouseup`/`keydown` events are the only ones that result in a click event?
2. Detach the existing `click` handlers, and manually call them from my new `mouseup`/`keydown` event handler?
3. Reliably detect the event that caused a `click` event to occur (e.g., somehow get access to the `keyCode`/`button` attributes for the initiating event)?

Comment: For your approach #2, you're using both `mouseup` and `keydown` event listeners, right? What does this mean: *I could envision some user agents enable changing the keys that ultimately send a `click` event to the underlying object*?

Comment: And do you mean: Perhaps touch-screens have some other event that is fired when *[touching/tapping]* on the DOM element?

Comment: What I am trying to get at is that there appears to be no way to know what events may ultimately result in a `click` event being fired.  Can I configure Firefox to fire a click event when an element has focus and I press the "P" key?  Any other browsers that allow such configuration?  How can I know that enter, space, and left-clicking (I use left here to mean primary mouse button) are the only means to fire a `click` event?  Are the requirements to fire a `click` event actually defined anywhere?